# Store program.exe has stopped working, How can I resolve it?

Tags: c, printf, scanf

I'm trying to compile the following code. When I give input to the program then after pressing enter a popup appears which shows that

> store program.exe has stopped working

Note: I am using Windows 8.1

Note: I am working on a program (which used in super stores), which includes the following things:

- Product code
- Product name
- Product price
- Total bill calculations

It's just the starting.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{
  int d, code;
  char product[100], price[100];    
  printf("\t\t Welcome to the Metro Store\n\n\n\n Enter your product code: ");
  scanf("%d",code);

  if(code<100)
    printf("Pharmacy\n Name of the Medicine");

  fflush(stdout);

  fgets(product, 100, stdin);
  printf(product);  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a good reason for reading code differently than product ?

Comment: do not mix `scanf()` and `fgets()`.

Comment: `scanf("%d",code);` --> `scanf("%d%*c", &code);`

Comment: "Stopped working" is an *extremely* generic error message, and virtually worthless to diagnose problems with. It's not even a proper error message; most of your software will "stop working" at some time. Since this is obviously a console program, do not run it by double-clicking it in Explorer; run in the command console, and you may get more useful data.

Answer (score 1):

For starters you should try

```
scanf("%d", &code);
```

You have to tell scanf where to write to. If you don't specify the ampersand (&), scanf will not know where is should write to.

You should read the [docs](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm) and definitely a good introduction to pointers. If you don't understand pointers, programming in C and C++ is pointless ;-)

Then you can change your `fgets()` to `scanf( "%s", product );`

In this case scanf does not need the `&` because `product` is short for `&product[0]`. This can get rather confusing, so get to grips with pointers before continuing.

Comment: for pointers, http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/102/PointersAndMemory.pdf would be a good start

Comment: please don't point to the c++ docs for questions tagged `c`. In this case it's harmless, but there must surely be better reference material =)

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin you are correct, in the case of scanf there is no difference. I linked to something "C only"

Answer (score 0):

- First, `scanf()` expects a pointer type variable as as an argument to the format specifier. Use

  ```
  scanf("%d", &code);
              ^^
  ```
- Second, do not mix up `scanf()` and `fgets()`. Otherwise, the `fgets()` will end up only consuming the `newline` left by `scanf("%d"..)`. Try to use `fgets()` for taking user input to be on safer side. However, if you have to use both, use something like

  ```
   scanf("%d", &code);
   int ch; while ((ch = getchar())!= EOF && ch != '\n');
   fgets(product,100,stdin);
  ```

  to avoid the issue with the *leftover* newline.